# onclick inline script can't reference id in the shadow-dom (Polymer v2.0)

Tags: polymer

Consider [this Plunker minimal example code](http://plnkr.co/edit/3NYhmYSo1QmJTu6UCUUY?p=preview).

```
<dom-module id="my-element">
  ...
  <button onclick="dialog.open()">What is Confucianism ?</button>

  <paper-dialog id="dialog" modal>
    <h2>Confucianism</h2>
    <p>...</p>
  </paper-dialog>
  ...
</dom-module>
```

won't work.

I am using **Polymer v2.0**. When I click on the button `dialog.open()` fails and says *dialog* is undefined.

In previous version of Polymer, this code worked but now that I have upgraded my code, I have to clear this issue everywhere I'm using *paper-dialog* elements. My current solution is to add a **on-click** attribute on all the buttons in my code and manually write a tied function and execute `this.$.<dialogID>.open();` but I don't understand why I have to do that, and it appears to be like an issue to me because I write more tedious code, and this afterward compatibility seems more like a disadvantage to the new version.

Am I really doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this approach is really bad. You should always call a function that will open dialog. Plus, you should use polymer event handlers. `on-tap` for example.

And why is your code no longer works? well it depends on if you are using shadow dom. Because in shadow DOM, there are shadowRoots which are, let's say closed, so `window` object no longer have elements with IDs saved as properties.

Normally, it works because whenever you define element with some ID, this element is saved inside `window` object and that's why you can do `<someID>.<someFunction>`.

You should definitely rewrite your app so it's using polymer event handler functions.

**EDIT:**

Consider this **Feature Request** [#4647](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/4647) for a future reliable solution.

Comment: @ballangddang thanks for edit and for good link. I am always watching changelogs so i hope i'll see this feature soon. It could really elp to remove many boilerplate functions